# How to fill a form outside a <form> with selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I'm trying to fill in a form. Here's my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('https://jazz.com.pk/choose-your-number')

prefixSelect = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ndc'))
criterionSelect = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'searchcriteria'))
patternInput = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'pattern')
searchButton = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'submit')

prefixSelect.select_by_visible_text('0307')
criterionSelect.select_by_visible_text('First 4 Digits')
patternInput.send_keys('7384')
```

This is the error I get:

```
line 19, in <module>
    prefixSelect.select_by_visible_text('0307')
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <option> could not be scrolled into view
```

Below I'm posting a series of code blocks with my attempts to fill in the form (notice there is no `<form>` element on the page), and the errors I encounter:

Attempt

```py
prefixSelect = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ndc'))
criterionSelect = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'searchcriteria'))
patternInput = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'pattern')
searchButton = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'submit')

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'option[value="0303"]')))

prefixSelect.select_by_visible_text('0307')
criterionSelect.select_by_visible_text('First 4 Digits')
patternInput.send_keys('7384')
```

Error

```
line 19, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'option[value="0303"]')))
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Attempt (Only the lines in between, for all attempts that follow)

```py
prefixOption = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'option[value="0307"]')
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(prefixOption).perform()
```

Error

```
line 20, in <module>
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(prefixOption).perform()
selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: Origin element <option> is not displayed
```

Attempt

```py
prefixOption = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'option[value="0307"]')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', prefixOption)
```

Error

```
line 22, in <module>
    prefixSelect.select_by_visible_text('0307')
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <option> could not be scrolled into view
```

Attempt

```py
prefixOption = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'option[value="0307"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseover'));", prefixOption)
```

Error

```
line 22, in <module>
    prefixSelect.select_by_visible_text('0307')
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <option> could not be scrolled into view
```

Then I tried to click the `<select>` which is already in view when the page is loaded.

Attempt

```py
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ndc').click()
```

Error

```
line 19, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ndc').click()
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <select id="ndc" class="ndc form-control mdbselectcustome abc w-100 select2-hidden-accessible" name="ndc"> could not be scrolled into view
```

Attempt

```py
for i in range(3):
    driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body').send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ndc').click()
```

Error

```
line 22, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ndc').click()
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <select id="ndc" class="ndc form-control mdbselectcustome abc w-100 select2-hidden-accessible" name="ndc"> could not be scrolled into view
```

Attempt

```py
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ndc')).perform()
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ndc').click()
```

Error

```
line 20, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ndc').click()
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <select id="ndc" class="ndc form-control mdbselectcustome abc w-100 select2-hidden-accessible" name="ndc"> could not be scrolled into view
```

Attempt

```py
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ndc'))
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ndc').click()
```

Error

```
line 20, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ndc').click()
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <select id="ndc" class="ndc form-control mdbselectcustome abc w-100 select2-hidden-accessible" name="ndc"> could not be scrolled into view
```

Attempt

```py
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseover'));", driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ndc'))
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ndc').click()
```

Error

```
line 20, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ndc').click()
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <select id="ndc" class="ndc form-control mdbselectcustome abc w-100 select2-hidden-accessible" name="ndc"> could not be scrolled into view
```

After all these attempts, maybe I can search more on the internet (probably just StackOverflow) and find out how to fill this form, but I just decided to ask here.

Please tell me how I can fill this form.

Comment: sounds like the select element you are targeting is hidden when you are trying to open it.  (are you sure you are targeting the correct one?) You may need to do something else to make it visible first, or wait for it to load.  The style is set to "hidden-accessible" which usually means it's hidden, but screenreader's will read it. (for blind people)

Comment: I think what you have here is a jQuery "Select2" control.  It hides the <select> element and puts it's own control over it.  (These options are <span, li, and other> tags.)  You've got to find those options after opening them and then click on them.) https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage

Answer (score 0):

Your element has custom rendered logic. Select is actually overridden by another element and is not visible.

To interact with dropdown you need to interact with element that is visible and clickable.

Visible element which represents dropdown has selector `[aria-labelledby=select2-ndc-container]`.

You just click on it and wait for dropdown options to be rendered by option selector `.select2-results [role=option]`.

After that you can filter elements with text exact match filter, click on it and wait for staleness of dropdown options.

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
dropdown = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[aria-labelledby=select2-ndc-container]')
dropdown.click()
options = wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.select2-results [role=option]')))
[element for element in options if element.text == '0307'][0].click()
wait.until(expected_conditions.staleness_of(options[0]))
```